# Ahiru no Sora - Does Sora not get along with his dad?

Tags: ahiru-no-sora

In episode 34 he says to his dad he no longer expects an allowance after one last thing. And even in the flashbacks it's always been Sora and his mum, did something happen between him and his dad?